# Python Tools: What parameter table type is best?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, parameters, python-toolbox

I'm trying to decide on the "best" choice for working with a set of input parameters. The data are table like. (several rows and columns)

As per: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm

There are several Parameter Data Types related to tables

- Record Set/GPRecordSet
- Value Table/GPValueTable
- Table/DETable
- Table View/GPTableView

There is information about Value Tables, I gather they are best suited for 2 dimensions.  But I can't find a lot of information about the other generic Table types, and why one would be chosen over the other.  They all seem to behave the same when creating a tool in a python toolbox.

Comment: What and how do you want the user of the tool you'll create to do? RecordSet is allows the user to interactively enter values into the table (inside the tool). TableView allows the user to point at a table in the map.

Comment: I'm using the tool to display and modify tabular configuration parameters.  At the moment I seem to have settled on RecordSet, but I still do not know if it's best or just what I have stumbled into.  I have found that DETable throws an error if empty on load.  I do wish there was better documentation on these.  They *all* seem to allow me to do edits in the table.